# How can I fixed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException which need correct entity id in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have got this exception :

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for   class com.netizenbd.domain.staff.StaffRegiAddressInfo. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class com.netizenbd.domain.staff.StaffRegiAddressInfo
```

when I want to delete StaffRegiAddressInfo object,
I have used manyToOne mapping in this Entity.

Here are code flow:

view code:

```
    <p:dataGrid value="#{staffUpdateMB.addressInfoList}"
        id="addesList" var="address" columns="1" layout="grid"
        styleClass="NoPadding NoIndent">
        <p:panel>
            <div
                class="Container100 Responsive100 TealGreenBack BordRad5 White NoIndent">

                <div class="Container50 Responsive100 NoIndent">
                    <h:outputText value="#{address.addressType}" styleClass="Fs22" />
                </div>
                <div class="Container50 Responsive100 TexAlRight NoIndent">
                    <p:commandButton class="TealGreenBack" icon="fa fa-edit"
                    onstart="PF('staffAddressEditDialog').show()">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{address}"
                            target="#{staffUpdateMB.beanAddressInfo}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton styleClass="RedButton RaisedButton"
                        action="#{staffUpdateMB.removeAddress}" icon="fa fa-trash-o"
                        update="addesList" ajax="false">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{address}"
                            target="#{staffUpdateMB.beanAddressInfo}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </div>
            </div>
    ... .... ....
    </p:panel>
    </p:dataGrid>
```

Here is ManageBean staffUpdateMB removeAddress(); method:

```
    public void removeAddress() {
    try {

        System.out.println("Address ID :"+this.beanAddressInfo.getAddressID());
        StaffRegiAddressInfo address=addressInfoDao.findById(this.beanAddressInfo.getAddressID());
        System.out.println("Address ID :"+address.getAddressID());
        addressInfoDao.remove(address);


        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(msg.getPropValue("deleteSuccess")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(msg.getPropValue("deleteError")));
        logger.error("This is error : " + e);
        logger.fatal("This is fatal : " + e);
    }
}
```

Here is addressInfoDao which extend EntityDao:

```
    public interface StaffRegiAddressInfoDao extends EntityDao<StaffRegiAddressInfo>{

    }

    public interface EntityDao<E> {

void persist(E e) throws Exception;

void merge(E e) throws Exception;

void remove(Object id) throws Exception;
    }
```

Here is the implementation EntityDao:

```
    public class EntityService<E>  implements EntityDao<E> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="persistenceUnit")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

protected E instance;
private Class<E> entityClass;


@Transactional
public void persist(E e) throws HibernateException{     
    getEntityManager().persist(e);
}
@Transactional
public void merge(E e) throws HibernateException{     
    getEntityManager().merge(e);
}
@Transactional
public void remove(Object id) throws Exception{     
    getEntityManager().remove((E)getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), id));
    getEntityManager().flush();
}
```

And Here is the Exception below:

```
    Address ID :33
    Address ID :33
    01/Mar/2016 18:14:05,440- StaffUpdateMB: This is error :      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.netizenbd.domain.staff.StaffRegiAddressInfo. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class com.netizenbd.domain.staff.StaffRegiAddressInfo
    01/Mar/2016 18:44:57,091- StaffUpdateMB: This is fatal : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.netizenbd.domain.staff.StaffRegiAddressInfo. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class com.netizenbd.domain.staff.StaffRegiAddressInfo
```

And Here also Entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="staffregi_addressinfo")
    public class StaffRegiAddressInfo implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="addressID")
private int addressID;

@Column(name="addressType")
private String addressType;

@Column(name="village")
private String village;

@Column(name="postOffice")
private String postOffice;

@Column(name="postalCode")
private String postalCode;

@Column(name="thanaName")
private String thanaName;

@Column(name="districtName")
private String districtName;

@Column(name="divisionName")
private String divisionName;

@Column(name="countryName")
private String countryName;

@Column(name="instituteID")
private String instituteID;

@Column(name="recordNote")
private String recordNote;

@Column(name="userExecuted")
private String userExecuted;

@Column(name="dateExecuted")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateExecuted;

@Column(name="ipExecuted")
private String ipExecuted;

@Column(name="recordStatus")
private int recordStatus;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="staffID")
private StaffRegiBasicInfo basicInfoAddress;
    //setter, getter also...
   }

   @Entity
   @Table(name="staffregi_basicinfo")
   public class StaffRegiBasicInfo implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="staffID")
private String staffID;

@Column(name="staffName")
private String staffName;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="basicInfoAddress")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Set<StaffRegiAddressInfo> addressInfoList;
//setter, getter also
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change in ManageBean staffUpdateMB removeAddress(); method:

> addressInfoDao.remove(address);

by

> addressInfoDao.remove(address.getAddressID());

in your DAO you have:

> public void remove(Object id);

but you are passing an object, not ID

Comment: Thanks, But when I use this addressInfoDao.remove(address.getAddressID()); then same exception occured

Comment: @AbuBakarSiddik so you mean that you set `address.getAddressID()` in your `remove` method of your `addressInfoDao` and you get the exception that this method expects an `int` class argument but a `StaffRegiAddressInfo` is provided instead? This is very strange since from your code `addressID` is integer. Can you check again please?

Comment: @elefasGR thank you, When I have changed 'addressID' 'int' to 'Integer' then no exception show. But data are not delete from DB

Comment: So you solved one problem, and now you have another one.
please either close this question and open a second one. or change the question to describe the new problem

Comment: @AbuBakarSiddik with no exceptions? can you check (via debug) if `(E)getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), id)` in `EntityService.remove()` returns you the entity you really want to delete? If there is an exception thrown please post it.

Comment: @elefasGR I have checked via debug with `(E)getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), id)` it returns my specific entity.But there is no exception when `EntityService.remove()` . And entity isn't deleted.